# Numeric Monetory Formatting in Python

Tags: formatting, python-3.x, currency

I am in a beginning computer science class and the assignment is to design a retirement planner with no user input.  I have designed a program that works:

```
def main():

    calcFinalBalance(age=30,rate=6,savings=3000)

def calcFinalBalance(age,rate,savings):
    balance = 0
    while age < 70:
        balance += savings
        balance = balance + (balance * ((rate)/100))
        age += 1

    print('$' + format(balance, ',.2f'))
main()
```

which computes $492,143.05

But it is not the correct formatting for the assignment.

I need to print`('$' + format(calcFinalBalance(30,6,3000), '.2f'))`
to compute my answer and I need to return values. I think I need to return balance after my while statement, my problem is I can't figure out how to pass values to my parameters without doing what I did above.  I keep getting parameter is not defined, if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is me again I got the program to work by assigning variables to my constants but now the program gives me my answer but then prints an a on the next line and the program doesn't stop running.  I'm guessing it has something to do with my while loop, but I'm not sure.  Here is my code.

Comment: def main():
    age = float(input('a'))
    rate = float(input('r'))
    savings = float(input('s'))    
    calcFinalBalance(a,r,s)

def calcFinalBalance(age,rate,savings):
    balance = 0
    while age < 70:
        balance += savings
        balance = balance + (balance * ((rate)/100))
        age += 1
    return balance
      
print('$' + format(calcFinalBalance(20,5.5,2000), ',.2f'))
main()

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what the problem is, but `calcFinalBalance(age=30,rate=6,savings=3000)` is equivalent to `calcFinalBalance(30,6,3000)` - it should work just as well. You can imagine 30 being inserted in the place of age, 6 in place of rate and 3000 in the place of savings.

The `format(calcFinalBalance(30,6,3000), '.2f'))` call indicates that `calcFinalBalance` should return a float, which I think it should do if you simply return `balance` from `calcFinalBalance` (right now you are printing it instead, thereby returning `None`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you?
It should print your balance with '$' sign. You can change the currency using the correct codes which you can find online.

```
>>> import babel.numbers
>>> import decimal
>>> babel.numbers.format_currency( decimal.Decimal( balance, "USD" )
```